# use a variable in a function or array

Tags: php, arrays, function

I'm trying to get a php file of a plugin that has been discontinued for three years to work, and not being a programmer I'm not succeeding ..
In practice, once the price has been extracted from the woocommerce cart, I want it to be used to update the price on a QR code generator.
The first part works, the second part works as well, but I can't get the "amount" parameter to read the $ total value.
Thanks to who will help me.

```
// WooCommerce 
    add_action( 'woocommerce_order_details_after_order_table', array( $this, 'order_details_after_order_table' ) );
  }

 
  /**
   * @todo refactor
   *
   * @param WC_Order $order
   */
  public function order_details_after_order_table( $order ) {
    $payment_method = $order->get_payment_method();
    $total          = $order->get_total();
    if ( $payment_method === 'bacs' ) {
      // temporary
      echo $this->shortcode_qrcode();
      echo $total;                                                      // correct return value (626)
    }
    

  }



  public function shortcode_qrcode( $atts = [] ) {
    $options = $this->options;

    // custom param
    $custom = shortcode_atts( array(
      'id'     => $options[ $this->field_key->field_promptpay_id ],
      'amount' => 0                                                     // I want use the $total in this point
    ), $atts );

    $html = sprintf( '<div class="ppy-card"
      data-promptpay-id="%s"
      data-amount="%f"
      data-show-promptpay-logo="%s"
      data-show-promptpay-id="%s"
      data-account-name="%s"
      data-shop-name="%s"
      data-card-style="%s"
      ></div>',
      $custom['id'],
      $custom['amount'],
      $options[ $this->field_key->field_show_promptpay_logo ],
      $options[ $this->field_key->field_show_promptpay_id ],
      $options[ $this->field_key->field_account_name ],
      $options[ $this->field_key->field_shop_name ],
      1
    );

    return $html;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome!

Well, that's very easy.
You only have to provide your call to "shortcode_qrcode( $atts = [] )"
with the parameter atts, an array containing your "amount" so that it gets replaced with your value for total.

```
public function order_details_after_order_table( $order ) {
        $payment_method = $order->get_payment_method();
        $total          = $order->get_total();
        if ( $payment_method === 'bacs' ) {
          // temporary
          echo $this->shortcode_qrcode(array("amount"=>$total)); // this would be the change to make
          echo $total; // correct return value (626)
        }
}
```